# proposing traffic selectors for us strongswan issue

Tags: logging, ipsec, strongswan

with the new stongswan module we get the following log message every second.

Is there a possibility to turn off these messages in the strongswan log ?

What does this message mean?

```
2017-12-12 08:20:29 12[CFG] proposing traffic selectors for other:
2017-12-12 08:20:29 12[CFG]  192.168.1.0/24
2017-12-12 08:20:29 12[CFG] proposing traffic selectors for us:
2017-12-12 08:20:29 12[CFG]  192.168.2.0/24
```

Comment: Are you querying the status every second, using a version < 5.7.0 and have the log level for _CFG_ set to 2 or higher?

Comment: @ecdsa Yes i am querying the status every second and i am using version strongSwan U5.5.1/K4.9.0-9-amd64

Answer (score 0):

In strongSwan versions older than 5.7.0 this message is not only logged when selecting traffic selector while establishing CHILD_SAs, but also whenever traffic selectors of a CHILD_SA configuration are enumerated, which e.g. happens when querying configured connections via VICI or stroke interface.

The messages are logged on level 2 in the *cfg* subsystem. So you can avoid them (and all other messages with the same level/subsystem) by [reducing the log level](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration) (the default log level is 1, by the way). Alternatively, update to a newer release where that message is not logged anymore when querying configuration objects.